# Unity: Dependency Injection

Tags: unity-container

public partial class HTCmds : ResourceDictionary
        {
            private ICanvasService mCanvasService;

```
        [Dependency]
        public ICanvasService CanvasService
        {
            get { return mCanvasService; }
            set { mCanvasService = value; }
        }

        public HTCmds()
        {
            CopyCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Copy, this.CanCopy);
            ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.Exit);
        }

        public DelegateCommand<object> CopyCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand<object> ExitCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Resource Dictionary Xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="HTCmds" 
                    x:ClassModifier="public"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:Commands;assembly=UIInfrastructure"
                    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Commands.Commands">
    <local:HTCmds x:Key="thisobj"/>
    <commands:CommandReference x:Key="CopyCommandReference" Command="{Binding  Source={StaticResource thisobj}, Path=CopyCommand}"/>
    <commands:CommandReference x:Key="ExitCommandReference" Command="{Binding  Source={StaticResource thisobj}, Path=ExitCommand}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I've registered the ICanvasService but it's not getting injected in this class. Resource Dictionary is merged in the xaml file of a windows class:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Commands/HTCmds.xaml" />
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

Is there something specific with ResourceDictionary class?

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal.

Comment: What is your question? Why do you think something is wrong? What should we look for in the code?

Comment: I am not able to get ICanvasService.

Comment: Where's your Unity registration?  Where do you register ICanvasService type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTCmds object is created by WPF by this line of XAML:

```
<local:HTCmds x:Key="thisobj"/>
```

WPF has no knowledge of Unity so it does not know how to resolve the dependencies using Unity.  You need to resolve objects using `UnityContainer.Resolve`.  You can't rely on WPF to do this for you.

Comment: According to Unity, If I decorate a property with [Dependency] attribute then it should resolve the dependency.
By the way, how do I resolve UnityContainer? If I can resolve Unity container then I can resolve ICanvasService.

Comment: Unity can only resolve if you are actually using Unity to create your objects. It does not magically intercept object creation and resolves dependencies.